# how can we change bytearray in a file(.xlsx or any) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, blob

I am getting a bytearray as response from my API which is converted from .xlsx file. Now I need to open/download this bytearray(after converting to its previous file extension) in browser. help me how can I do that? I'm helpless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read data in browser, client side with `readAsArrayBuffer` [more docs on mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) .

But I am not sure you'll be able to parse the contents of .xlsx in plain JS, here's example of library which does that: http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/ which is

> XLSX / XLSM / XLSB / XLS / SpreadsheetML (Excel Spreadsheet) / ODS
>   parser and writer

Answer (score -1):

```
openPDF(data, "DataSheet.pdf");//data is your bytearray intead of pdf try to ur file format

// ...

function openPDF(resData, fileName) {
    var ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/g);
    var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/.NET/g); // IE 11+
    var oldIE = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g);

    var blob = new $window.Blob([resData], {
        type: 'application/pdf'
    });

    if (ie || oldIE || ieEDGE) {
        $window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {

        var file = new Blob([resData], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

        $window.open(fileURL);
    }
}
```